# MIPS use string on arguments of function

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have this function on MIPS, this convert lowercase to upper case the string on the buffer :

```
funcion:
    addi $t0,$zero,0

    loop:
        lb $t1, buffer($t0)
        beq $t1, 0, exit_loop
        blt $t1, 'a', case
        bgt $t1, 'z', case
        sub $t1, $t1, 32
        sb $t1, buffer($t0)

    case: 
            addi $t0, $t0, 1
            j loop

    exit_loop:
        jr $ra

    .data

buffer: .asciiz "Meow"
buffer2: .asciiz "Guau"
```

I want use it for buffer2, how a can send the string like argument to the function?

I try this

```
    la $a0,buffer

    jal convertir_a_mayusculas
```

and changing the loop function

```
    loop:
        lb $t1, $a0($t0)
        beq $t1, 0, exit_loop
        blt $t1, 'a', case
        bgt $t1, 'z', case
        sub $t1, $t1, 32
        sb $t1, $a0($t0)
```

But doesn't work, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a0($t0)` is not a valid addressing mode because it has two registers, the good news is that you don't need `$t0` at all: just increment `$a0`.

```
funcion:

    loop:
        lb $t1, ($a0)
        beq $t1, 0, exit_loop
        blt $t1, 'a', case
        bgt $t1, 'z', case
        sub $t1, $t1, 32
        sb $t1, ($a0)

    case: 
            addi $a0, $a0, 1
            j loop

    exit_loop:
        jr $ra
```

You may have to change `($a0)` into `0($a0)` if pseudo-instructions are not enabled in MARS settings.

This clobber `$a0`, I don't remember if the MIPS calling convention make it volatile or not, in case you need to preserve it, just copy it to `t0` at the beginning of the function and use `t0` thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Using a register to hold the sting address as in the second try is the proper way.

Using `lb $t1, buffer($t0)` may create problems if buffer is more than 16 bits.  It can work in small examples, but is dangerous in real code.

The main problem with your second try is that instruction `lb $t1, $a0($t0)` is syntactically incorrect. `lb` requires a destination register, an address register and an offset that **must** be an immediate.

So, as address of buffer is already in `$a0`, you can use  `lb $t1, 0($a0)` and increment `$a0` in your loop to access successive chars.

```
loop:
    lb $t1, 0($a0)       # loads byte at address $a0+0
    beq $t1, 0, exit_loop
    blt $t1, 'a', case
    bgt $t1, 'z', case
    sub $t1, $t1, 32
    sb $t1, 0($a0)
case: 
    addi $a0, $a0, 1    # let $a0 point to next char in buffer
    j loop
exit_loop:
    jr $ra
```